# Blender "Rigacar" won't properly follow a Nurbs Circle

Tags: filmic-blender, blenderkit

when I try to make my car follow a circle the car will lock on to the path, however it has a weird bobbing/jittering motion every couple of frames. This does not happen when I make the car follow a straight path or a curvy path. This only happens with a Nurbs circle. Can someone explain what's wrong? I'm trying to make the car do donuts (drifting)

It won't let me put a video but the car will follow this path and have 2 weird jitters per every one rotation.

. [image]

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file: https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Sure I have 2 circles however I want to use the Nurbs circle not the bezier. I left both in the scene. Please let me know and thanks. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JGqYslXL7wNN0oxWPKXKlnDwwJt6hgB5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Austin your file is too large. i don't think we need all of the data that is in your file, kindly strip down as much as data as you can and only leave that which is important to reproduce the issue. You can also use *File->Clean Up* after deleting all unnecessary data.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Agreed, it's almost 1GB